# Wider width or larger width?

Tags: phrases

I'm hesitating between these two and I don't know which one is more correct: wider width or larger width?

Comment: I would say "greater".  (Unless it's a kitchen utensil, in which case I'd use "grater".)

Comment: It's hard to tell which would be better when we can't see the whole sentence.

Comment: Would you please provide more detail and some examples of usage? What research have you done prior to asking this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wider%20width%2Clarger%20width&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwider%20width%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clarger%20width%3B%2Cc0) evidence shows a preference of larger vs wider, but both are correct.

From: [Journal of the Optical Society of America.](https://books.google.it/books?id=TyUXAQAAMAAJ&q=%22larger%20width%22&dq=%22larger%20width%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0kLrX7bzjAhVCzqQKHcrPCPI4HhDoAQg-MAU)

> Width affected only the accuracy of the slope estimate (accuracy was better for the smaller width) and the bias of the width estimate (*bias was smaller for the larger width).*

From: [Wider Buses and the Interstate Highway System,](https://books.google.it/books?id=fGP2cM9HK0IC&q=%22wider%20width%22&dq=%22wider%20width%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjWsYXv7LzjAhVC_aQKHey-A4cQ6AEITTAH)

> There should be no decision on this measure until a full study is completed. *Then, if the wider width is found to be safe* — which we doubt at this time — action could be taken.

Comment: Seems like [greater width](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wider+width%2Clarger+width%2Cgreater+width&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=15) is even more prevalent.

Comment: Both are used though, depending on context.